# Object doesn't show on leaflet angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, leaflet

I'm making a little app for training with AngularJS, and I have a problem. 
I'm receiving JSON data through an API, and then I display it in a map using leaflet directives for Angular.

The problem is one of the thing I try to display give me an error.

This is my controller :

```
toulouseVeloControllers.controller('toulouseVeloListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {

      angular.extend($scope, {
          osloCenter: {},
          markers: {},
          defaults: {
              scrollWheelZoom: false
          }
      });


      $http.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=toulouse&apiKey=*************************************').success(function(data) {

          $scope.bornes = data;

          $scope.markers=[];
          $scope.osloCenter=[];

          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

              $scope.markers[i] = {
                  lat: data[i].position.lat,
                  lng: data[i].position.lng,
                  message: data[i].available_bikes,
                  focus: false,
                  draggable: false
              };
          }

          $scope.osloCenter = {
              lat: data[10].position.lat,
              lng: data[10].position.lng,
              zoom: 15
          };
      });
  }]);
```

And this is my HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="toulouseVeloListCtrl">
    <leaflet markers="markers" center="osloCenter" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></leaflet>
</div>
```

In `$scope.markers[i]`, when I try to show `data[i].available_bikes`, it give me an error, but if I try to show other like `data[i].name` or `data[i].address`, there is no problem.

Anyone can tell me what is wrong here ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: You need to mention the error that you get.

Comment: Right now I haven't an error in the console, but in my popup, insteed of the value of data[i].available_bikes, I get "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the popup needs to be a string.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    $scope.markers[i] = {
        lat: data[i].position.lat,
        lng: data[i].position.lng,
        message: "Available Bikes: " + data[i].available_bikes,
        focus: false,
        draggable: false
    };
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tombatossals/4PhzC/